# Utilizar variavel mais vezes, click event

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um select HTML e altero o valor de uma variavel depois de passa pela função onchange(). O problema é que tenho outra condição e não consigo validar.

JS:

```
//function mode select
var option = 0
function getData(val) {
if (val.value === "option1"){
    option = 1
    alert("option deplacement!");
}else{  
    option = 2
    alert("option ligne!");

} 
 show();
}

function show() {
   console.log(this.option);
    val = this.option
    if (val == 2){
        var el = document.getElementById('id_click');
        el.onclick = function (e) {
            alert("click2")
            var ev = e || window.event;
            var x2 = el.getAttributeNS(null, "x"); 
            var y2 = el.getAttributeNS(null, "y"); 
            //console.log(x2+" "+y2)
        }
    }
 }
```

HTML:

```
<select id="selectid" onChange="getData(this);" >
   <option value="option1">Deplacement</option>
   <option value="option2">lignes</option>
</select>
<div id="id_div">dfsd</div>
```

Exemplo no [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnz200tv/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo fato da variável `option` estar definida no escopo global e uma função declarativa, como a sua, receber o `this` diretamente do escopo global é possível usar o `this`. Neste caso você pode simplesmente adicionar o `this` na variavel option dentro da função, exemplo: `this.option = 1;`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/vnz200tv/14/)

```js
// Variavel definina em escopo global.
var option = 0;

function getData(elemento) {
  
  // atribui valor a variavel option usando o operador ternário.
  this.option = elemento.value === 'option1' ? 1 : 2;
}

function clicked(elemento) {
 if(this.option === 2) {
     elemento.innerHTML = "você clicou e a cor mudou.";
        elemento.style.background = 'tomato';
    } else {
        elemento.innerHTML = "você pode até clicar mas nada acontecerá.";
    }
}
```

```css
div {
    background: lightgray;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select id="selectid" onChange="getData(this);" >
 <option value="option1">Deplacement</option>
 <option value="option2">lignes</option>
</select>

<div onclick="clicked(this);"></div>
```

Comment: editei utilizando esse codigo, quero um onclick event na função show.

Comment: @akm A função show foi criada para apenas mostrar que o `option` foi alterado e está visível em qualquer parte do escopo. Crie um evento `onclick` atribuindo ao elemento que deseja e use o `this.option` para validar o valor na função.

Comment: Tenho uma div, e quando clico nela aparece o evento onclick. Dentro da funçao nao consigo identificar o elemento. Quero que so da para clicar quando o select é 2.

Comment: @akm impedir de clicar em um elemento não é possível, a não ser que você desconecte o mouse da usuário, brincadeira. Então... se a sua intenção é executar uma ação ao clicar na `div` apenas quando `option` for 2 é só fazer um `if` para validar. Eu alterei o código, de uma olhada no jsFiddle se preferir.

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar o `switch` para fazer esta operação e deixa-la mais legivel, tente desta maneira.

```
function getData(val)
{
var option = 0
switch(val.value) {
    case "option1":
        option = 1
        alert("option deplacement!");
        break;
    case "option2":
        option = 2
        alert("option ligne!");
        break;
    default:
        option = 0;
  }
if (option == 2) {
    alert("Option2");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloca o `IF` dentro da função também

```
var option = 0
function getData(val) {
    if (val.value === "option1"){
        option = 1
        alert("option deplacement!");
    }else{  
        option = 2
        alert("option ligne!");
    }

    if(option==2){
        alert("option2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas tenho outra função depois dentros desse função, o evento onclick.

Comment: var el = document.getElementById('co1');
el.onclick = function (e) { }

Comment: Posta tudo na sua pergunta.

Comment: editei o jsfiddle, quero um click quando estou na segunda opção do select